# How to access an element of a vector while using lapply over a list

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I want to add rows to a data frame such that the first column contains all numbers between 1 to 10 and depending on the number, the second column should have a certain output.

I can do this using a for-loop as below:

```
Dt <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,5,7,8), Value = "x", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Special_cases <- c(3,4)

for (i in 1:10){

  if( i %in% Dt$ID){

    Dt <- Dt

  } else if (i %in% Special_cases){

    Dt <- rbind(Dt, c(i,"y"))

  } else {

    Dt <- rbind(Dt, c(i,"z"))

  }

}

 ID Value
1   1     x
2   2     x
3   5     x
4   7     x
5   8     x
6   3     y
7   4     y
8   6     z
9   9     z
10 10     z
```

Although this works, I want to get out of this bad habit of using for-loops, but i've been struggling to re-write this using lapply. I'm not sure how to deal with the first if statement where I call on `i`.

So how can I transform this for-loop to lapply? I'm also not sure what the first argument of lapply would be.

Comment: What's the logic here? Will all the `x` values always come from that first data.frame? And you're just hard coding the `y` values at 3 and 4? And everything else is `z`? I'm not clear what the input is or what the output would look like under different conditions.

Comment: That's correct. My original problem's dataframe required ID = 1:100 as the first column, but due to the nature of my problem, not all 100 values were inside the dataframe. So I required a method to check if, for example ID = 15 was missing from the data frame, a row would be created with ID = 15, and value = z as 15 is not a special case. I've adjusted the question to emphasize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this one works. First, run `lapply` over your vector of desired IDs, creating a list of one-row data frames per your specifications.

```
results <- lapply(seq(10), function(i) {

    if (i %in% Dt$ID) {

        Dt[which(Dt$ID==i),]

    } else if (i %in% c(3,4)) {

        data.frame(ID = i, Value = "y")        

    } else {

        data.frame(ID = i, Value = "z") 

    }

})
```

Then, collapse that list into a data frame. You could also roll this into the previous step by nesting the call to `lapply` where `results` appears here.

```
Dt2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

If you don't mind introducing a dependency on `tidyverse`' or `purrr` in particular, you can also substitute `map_dfr` for `lapply` in the code block above, and it will go ahead and collapse the resulting list into one data frame in that same step. Note, though, that it will also throw warnings about converting a factor to a character to do that, even though all those IDs were characters in the first place.

Here's the result. Note that you would still need to sort according to `Value` if you cared about having things grouped by that feature.

```
   ID Value
1   1     x
2   2     x
11  3     y
12  4     y
3   5     x
13  6     z
4   7     x
5   8     x
14  9     z
15 10     z
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you say this is a better approach than the for loop? My for-loop seems easier to read but the whole R community is adamant on replacing for loops with apply functions

Comment: It should be faster. The difference probably wouldn't matter with a small data set, but as your data set grows, it would probably be significant.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be another way using merges from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(ID=1:10) %>% left_join(Dt) %>% 
  left_join(tibble(ID=Special_cases, Value2="y")) %>% 
  mutate(Value=coalesce(Value, Value2, "z"), Value2=NULL)
```

Or here's another way that doesn't involved loops or lapply. Just see what's missing and add it all in one go.

```
if (any(!Special_cases %in% Dt$ID)) {
  Dt <- rbind(Dt, data.frame(ID = setdiff(Special_cases, Dt$ID), Value = "y", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
if (any(!1:10 %in% Dt$ID)) {
  Dt <- rbind(Dt, data.frame(ID = setdiff(1:10, Dt$ID), Value = "z", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```